# How to calculate the coordinate of a point on circle, which is connected to a point inside circle and the center?

Tags: circles, coordinate-systems

The below image is the situation:

[The circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxaYj.png)

In the above image, the coordinates of center O and point A, and the radius r are known, while the coordinate of point B is unknown. The only things we know about point B are that it is on the circle, and it is on the same line with center O and point A. Point A can be any point on the line and can only be between center O and point B. Then the question is, how to find the coordinate of B?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vector form, assuming $0 < d(O,A) \le r$, we have
$$\vec{B}=\vec{O}+r\frac{\vec{OA}}{d(O,A)}$$
hence, letting
$$(x_O,y_O),\;\;\;(x_A,y_A),\;\;\;(x_B,y_B)$$
denote the coordinates of $O,A,B$, respectively, we get
\begin{align*}
x_B&=x_O+\frac{r}{\sqrt{(x_A-x_O)^2 + (y_A-y_O)^2}}(x_A-x_O)\\[4pt]
y_B&=y_O+\frac{r}{\sqrt{(x_A-x_O)^2 + (y_A-y_O)^2}}(y_A-y_O)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}